# Spring.Net throws an exception: Request is not available in this context

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, spring.net

I'm very new to Spring, so some decisions are not clear for me
This is ASP.NET MVC4 / .NET 4.5 application

This is a text of exception:

```
An exception of type 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' occurred in Spring.Core.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Error creating context 'spring.root': Request is not available in this context
```

Error throws in custom Context manager class:

```
    public static IApplicationContext GetApplicationContext()
    {
        if (null == appContext)
        {
            lock (typeof(ContextManager))
            {
                if (null == appContext)
                {
                    appContext = ContextRegistry.GetContext(); <-- throws there
                }
            }
        }
        return appContext;
    }
```

Lots of solutions, I'd googled, tells me to switch **IIS Mode to Integrated Mode**. In that mode application works fine, but I need to debug app with **IISExpress**. And there are no any ideas

There is my stack trace for this exception:

at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.EvaluateOne(String[] keys, SectionInput input, Boolean isTrusted, FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.Evaluate(FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult, Boolean getLkg, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String configKey)
   at System.Web.HttpContext.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at System.Web.Configuration.HttpConfigurationSystem.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at System.Web.Configuration.HttpConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String configKey)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at Spring.Util.ConfigurationUtils.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at Spring.Context.Support.ContextRegistry.InitializeContextIfNeeded()
   at Spring.Context.Support.ContextRegistry.GetContext()
   at HealthDec.Cms.Model.ContextManager.GetApplicationContext() in ~~\Model\ContextManager.cs:line 46
   at HealthDec.Cms.Model.ContextManager.GetObject(String name) in ~~\Model\ContextManager.cs:line 64
   at HealthDec.Cms.WebApp.MvcApplication.Init() in ~~\Applications\WebApp\Global.asax.cs:line 156
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers)

Comment: You most likely try to access the spring.net `Context` to early in the application life-cycle (it differs between classic and integrated mode). If your application is derived from `SpringMvcApplication` override the `ConfigureApplicationContext` to gain access to the context.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I'm stuck in a pickle:
- Forced to use `Integrated Pipeline Mode` for OWIN support
- However the mode doesn't load `Request` on `Application_Start` where I load Spring's objects. Note: I need to perform business logic on app start.

Comment: @Exegesis not sure why it should be some request object on application initialization part? Honestly, I don't remember the context of ~6 year aged task, but the only thing worked for me was an answer I already posted (so this actually is "solution to this problem")

Answer (score 3):

Solution Explorer -> Select MVC project -> Properties tab -> Managed Pipeline Mode -> Integrated <--> Classic

Comment: @AMomchilov: it was a single solution in my case. I will be glad if you provide something better

Comment: I'm still looking for one myself :(